# C# Displaying revision/build number in webservice description?

Tags: c#, web-services

is it possible to display the revision/build number in the webservice description?
I want the users to see what version that is currently up and running when they go to the url for the webservice.

Ex.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://webservice.mydomain.com/", Name = "webservice for multimedia devices", Description = "Last build: **xxxxx**")]
```

I want to get it dynamically if possible (`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()`)

I also tried this (suggestion see below). This got the description but it could not update it before it showed the webservice to the client.

```
var t = typeof(webClient);
var att = (WebServiceAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebServiceAttribute), true)[0];
att.Description = "Current running version: " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't verified it, but try this:

```
WebServiceAttribute att = (NamespaceAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(WebServiceAttribute))[0];

att.Description = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

This has to be done at some suitable point during startup.

Comment: Does not seem to work. I added this: var t = typeof(webClient); 
var att = (WebServiceAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebServiceAttribute), false)[0];
 att.Description = "Current running version: " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;

Comment: This got the description but did not update it. I forgot to mention that i use .NET 3.5 and not 4.

Comment: Have you tried adding this code in a custom ServiceHostFactory (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx)? I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you need to manually define the assembly info and version first, then use Reflection to get it back out at runtime.  By default, there doesn't seem to be a concept of a "version #" for an ASP.NET app unless you define it yourself.

This article shows how to do it.  The article shows how to get a lot more than just the version #, but it's in there.

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/ASP.NET:_Display_Version_Information

Comment: The problem still remains. I need to present this in the webservice description.